# Why are my JavaScript Date/Time objects stored as maps as opposed to timestamps in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Difference between timestamp and map with nanoseconds / seconds]

The attached image is a screenshot of two "date/time" entries in my Firestore document.

**timeCompleted** is a value that I entered directly in the database, choosing "timestamp" as the field's type. Per the screenshot, you can tell that the date/time shows in a readable format (not that it matters to me).

**timeCreated** is a value added by my JavaScript Reactjs application, using `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(myDate + " " + myTime))`, as prescribed by the [Google docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types). As opposed to being stored as a timestamp type, it is stored as a map containing nanoseconds and seconds.

Is there a way to store my JavaScript date (timeCreated) as a true timestamp, similarly to timeCompleted?

**My firebase class (gets imported through React's Context API)**

```
import app from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions";

const config = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  databaseURL: ...,
  projectId: ...
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.firestore = app.firestore;
    this.functions = app.functions;
 }
}
export default Firebase;
```

**My React Component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { FirebaseContext } from "../../Firebase";

const InnerComponent = React.memo(props => {
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);

//Calls Google Cloud function below
firebase.functions().httpsCallable("storeInDb")({
  const myDate = "2019-02-25";
  const myTime = "17:45";
  orderDetails {
    name: "someName",
    timeCreated: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(myDate + " " + myTime))
  }
)}
```

**My Google Cloud Function**

```
exports.storeInDb = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return id = await orderCreation(data.orderDetails);
});

const orderCreation = async orderDetails => {
  try {
    const docRef = await admin.firestore()
     .collection(pathToCollection...)
     .add(orderDetails);
    return docRef.id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ORDER CREATION ERROR", error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **entire** bit of code that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.  Please also read about how to create an MCVE for use on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the type of the Timestamp object that you're passing into the callable function to be retained between the client and server.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.  When a Timestamp object is serialized, it just converts to a JavaScript object with seconds and nanoseconds properties.  The callable function on the other side isn't going to automatically reconstitute that object into a Timestamp.  In fact, all types are lost, and everything is just converted to JSON.

What you're going to have to do is take that serialized object in the function and turn it back into a Timestamp yourself before you pass it to the Firestore SDK.  Then, the SDK will arrange for Firestore to save it as a timestamp type field.  This means you're going to have to do some initial processing on the `data` parameter and make sure it has all the correct values to write into Firestore.

Again, if it's not completely clear - the type of the object must be correct with the Firestore SDK calls.  You can't pass arbitrary objects and expect it to do smart conversions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.